# VIM: Ruby methods with ? and ! in the end

Tags: ruby, vim

I'm trying to use VIM completion (dictionary and current buffer), but i'm running into issues with ? and ! in the end of method names. Can i somehow explain to vim that method names (words basically) can have it only in the end and only one i.e. method_name? not bull???!!shit!? or if !xyz ... (when ? and ! added iskeyword !xyz exists in completion list). Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: It seems there is no way to use pattern in `iskeyword`definition but only characters. I can see how it could be useful in ruby case...

Comment: thats why i've got thought to create new editor :)

Answer (score 5):

IIRC, you have to modify the `iskeyword`option.

You can try `set iskeyword+=?,!`so that `?` and `!` are considered as part of words and not separator.

In your `.vimrc`, you can add :
`autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.rb set iskeyword+=?,!`

See `:help iskeyword`for more information.

Edit : I had not seen you had already mentioned iskeyword as a possible workaround.

Alternate idea :
1. Generate ctags for your ruby code.
2. in the `complete` option remove everything except the `t` option meaning `tags only`.

You are only going to have suggestions coming from the tag file. The downside is that it adds a new step to use completion and you will miss some non-tag completion.

Comment: please read original message carefully. iskeyword doesn't work in this case, because adding ? and ! to it means after something like `if !xyz` there'll be new completion option !xyz and thats definitely not what i want. generating tags on each change? not the best idea either.

Comment: Your alternate solution seems to be the most viable in this situation.  +1.